# Groovy / jsonSlurper using OR (IN) in assertion

Tags: groovy, assertion, jsonslurper

```
//verify if successful transaction

assert jsonSlurper.body.message == "Approved"
```

I want this to be True for either "Approved" and "Aprobada" and this doesn't work:

```
assert jsonSlurper.body.message IN ("Approved","Aprobada")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower case `in` with a proper list should work too

```
assert jsonSlurper.body.message in ["Approved","Aprobada"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually got it:

```
assert jsonSlurper.body.message == "Approved" || jsonSlurper.body.message == "Aprobada"
```